# How can I adjust the Geany date format when using a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: geany, geany-plugin

In [Geany](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geany), you can use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to insert the current date at the cursor position. For me it inserts:

```
27.05.2016
```

How can I edit the format of it to be `dd/mm/yyyy`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to menu *Edit* → *Insert Date* → *Set Custom Date Format*.

There you can set the format used for that shortcut.

Comment: This does not work for me. I have updated the format there to use "/" as a separator but still getting "." (dot). Restarting Geany does not help.

Comment: @Michal Przybylowicz: If it didn't work, why did you accept it?

Comment: It worked when I tried it with Geany v. 1.35 on Linux and Geany v. 1.36 on Windows. For [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date and time: `%Y-%m-%dT%H%M%S` (sample: *2020-05-22T165001*). Only ISO 8601 date: `%Y-%m-%d` (sample: *2020-05-22*)